# Magento Template process

Tags: magento, templates

Im doing the front end for an e-comm site using the Magento platform. I havent used Magento yet, my sole task is front end, however looking at the way Magento is structured its gonna be alot harder than I thought.

We have a Magento developer which will be incharge of the back end.

My question is, Can i make static HTML files for example PDP.html that will run independently in the browser and hand them to the Magento developer for him to incorporate into a new Magento theme?

The reason for this, I can make these templates a lot faster this way.

For the Magento guru's out there, is it a big pain in the bum when front ends do it like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not that difficult. Try using CMS/Pages and creating a static HTML page. If you just want to create a block, say a part of the page, use CMS/Static Blocks. This way your Magento dev can easily call your page/block.

Comment: Cheers mate, I will have a look